# Uninstalling Exchange 2007 - creating a secondary domain controller

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange-2007, domain-controller

I previously had Exchange 2007 on a Windows Server 2008 x64 machine (not R2). I migrated everything to Exchange 2010 and uninstalled Exchange 2007.

I want to use this server as another DC. My question is, how should I go about this?

Should I remove the server from the domain, rename it, rejoin and go from there or should I remove the server from the domain, reformat it, reinstall windows, rejoin and so on.

I want to make sure I have the right method before starting the process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you uninstalled Exchange, then you shouldn't have any problem.  That said, I'm a huge fan of starting fresh when you can.  That eliminates any possibility of something hanging around and causing you grief later on.  My recommendation would be to disjoin from the domain, wipe and reinstall, then join to the domain and promote.

Comment: I have to agree with "start fresh when you can". Without wanting to sound like I'm having a dig at the OP, with our WDS deployment servers containing server images as well as workstation images, where I work, we'd be most of the way through a clean install of Windows Server in the time its taken to get an answer. If you're hoping to get a few years reliable service out of a system then an hour extra in the process of setting it up is well worth the "price".

Comment: i agree with both of - i normally go for clean installs but i figured i would ask